# UITextInput returns nil position only in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextinput, uitextrange

I am trying to get the rect of a specific range (`UITextRange`).
The problem is that the code works fine with `iOS 10` , and I am getting 
the range and rect. Unfortunately with `iOS 9` the line :

```
if let rangeStart = textInput.position(from: textInput.beginningOfDocument, offset: location)
```

returns `nil`

```
let location = self.textView.firstRect(for: range)


extension NSRange {
    func toTextRange(textInput:UITextInput) -> UITextRange? {
        if let rangeStart = textInput.position(from: textInput.beginningOfDocument, offset: location),
            let rangeEnd = textInput.position(from: rangeStart, offset: length) {
            return textInput.textRange(from: rangeStart, to: rangeEnd)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`textView.isSelectable = true`

This line is necessary in iOS 9 (not necessary in iOS 10).